# Remove duplicate rows in R and add entries of removed rows to kept row

Tags: r, duplicates

I have data like this:

```
df <-

a b c
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 9

2 3 3
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 3 9

3 4 3
3 4 4
3 4 5
3 4 9
```

I want to remove duplicate rows base on column a but keep the values in column c as in:

```
df2 <-

a b c c1 c2 c3
1 2 3 4  5  9
2 3 3 4  5  9
3 4 3 4  5  9
```

I know how to remove duplicates as in :

```
df2 <-df[!(df$a=="1"),]
```

But have now idea how to add the values to the kept row.

Comment: It's really hard to see what logic you're trying to apply here, since you have the same values in multiple columns. Are you discarding `b` besides the first and pivoting out he `c` values?

Comment: So I have duplicate row which are completely identical except for one column value. I want to delete the duplicate rows but keep the unique values of the deleted rows. You are completely right that my example is not very logical. Ill correct it.

Comment: @Valentin can you please check my solution updated

Answer (score 0):

We can exclude `c` while subsettting the rows of the dataset, `unlist`, and then concatenate with the whole 'c' column

```
c(unlist(df[!duplicated(df$a), 1:2]), c = df$c)
#  a  b c1 c2 c3 c4 
#  1  2  3  4  5  9
```

---

If we need the same names as in the expected

```
c(unlist(df[!duplicated(df$a), 1:2]), 
      setNames(df$c, make.unique(rep('c', nrow(df)),  sep="")))
# a  b  c c1 c2 c3 
#  1  2  3  4  5  9
```

---

With the new example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarise(b = first(b), c = list(as.list(c))) %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(c))%>% 
    rename_at(vars(starts_with('.')), ~ str_c('c', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#      a     b    c1    c2    c3    c4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3     4     5     9
#2     2     2     3     4     5     9
```

---

Or with again updated example

```
df3 %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   summarise(b = first(b), c = list(as.list(c))) %>% 
   unnest_wider(c(c))%>% 
   rename_at(vars(starts_with('.')), ~ str_c('c', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#      a     b    c1    c2    c3    c4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3     4     5     9
#2     2     3     3     4     5     9
#3     3     4     3     4     5     9
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df3)[, c(.(b = first(b)),  
       as.data.frame.list(setNames(c, rep('c', .N)))), a] 
#    a b c c.1 c.2 c.3
#1: 1 2 3   4   5   9
#2: 2 3 3   4   5   9
#3: 3 4 3   4   5   9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
    c = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), b = c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), c = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))



df3 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), c = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: I will look at it. In the meantime I adjsuted my example. Not that you are wondering.